# How do add strings to a json file in python from an dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a little question! How can I add an object or string to an already existing JSON file in Python?

At the moment I have written that snip of code. But is it going to always add a new JSON file. I hope you know my problem. :D

```
json.dump(txtdictionary_main,open('filename-manager.json','w'),indent=4,sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: you have to read all data from JSON file to memory (as list or dictionary), add new values (to this list or dictionary), and save all data again to file JSON. You can't append directly to existing file because it will create incorrect JSON file.

Comment: oh ok thank you for your help. But how should I do that. Sorry but I am new at Python and I don't know how do to that

Comment: you have to read all data from file to memory using `open()` and `read()` and use `json.loads()` to convert to Python structure (list/dictonary), and then add new values to this list/dictonary. And finally you have to use `json.dump()` to save all data from this list/dictionary in file.

Comment: Yea that sounds very helpful.Thanks for your help. I am going to try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert file to dictionary:

```
with open('filename-manager.json') as json_file:
  txtdictionary_main = json.load(json_file)
```

Add values to dictionary:

```
txtdictionary_main[key] = value
```

Convert dictionary back to JSON:

```
json_object = json.dumps(txtdictionary_main , indent = 4)
```

Comment: By "Add values to dictionary" there you mean that I can take a string for example and add it to the dictionary and after that I have to convert it back to a "updated" Version of the JSON File?

Comment: yes, I will edit to add code for adding to dictionary